# User not getting chatter email notifications

Tags: chatter

The user is not getting chatter email notifications after a tracked field update is made to the account the user follows. The user has also added the account to the chatter stream named "Account stream". The notification settings for the stream are set to Every Post.

Chatter email settings are as below:[image]

In the sandbox, the email deliverability is set to All Email.

Let me know what the issue could be.

Comment: is the user's email actually valid? Did they update it in the sandbox?

Comment: yes, users email is valid.